# Handles clause requires a withevents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types error

Tags: vb.net, events

Not sure why im getting this error or how to fix it.. Appreciate all help

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    ' Class-level variables
    Private strFilename As String = String.Empty    ' Document filename
    Dim blnIsChanged As Boolean = False             ' File change flag

    Sub ClearDocument()
        ' Clear the contents of the text box.
        txtDocument.Clear()

        ' Clear the document name.
        strFilename = String.Empty

        ' Set isChanged to False.
        blnIsChanged = False
    End Sub

    ' The OpenDocument procedure opens a file and loads it 
    ' into the TextBox for editing.

    Sub OpenDocument(ByVal strFilename As String)
        Dim inputFile As StreamReader               ' Object variable

        ' If called without an argument, browse a file using
        ' Windows Forms
        If strFilename = Nothing Then
            If ofdOpenFile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                ' Retrive selected filename
                strFilename = ofdOpenFile.FileName
            End If
        End If

        Try
            ' Open the file.
            inputFile = File.OpenText(strFilename)

            ' Read the file's contents into TextBox.
            txtDocument.Text = inputFile.ReadToEnd()

            ' Close the file.
            inputFile.Close()

            ' Update isChanged variable.
            blnIsChanged = False

            ' Display the name of the file.
            Me.Text = "Simple Text Editor - " & strFilename

        Catch
            ' Error message for file open error.
            MessageBox.Show("Error opening the file.")
        End Try

    End Sub


    ' The SaveDocument procedure saves current document.

    Sub SaveDocument()
        Dim outputFile As StreamWriter      ' Object varibale

        Try
            ' Create the file.
            outputFile = File.CreateText(strFilename)

            ' Write the TextBok to file.
            outputFile.Write(txtDocument.Text)

            ' Close the file.
            outputFile.Close()

            ' Update isChanged varibale.
            blnIsChanged = False
        Catch
            ' Error message for file creation error.
            MessageBox.Show("Error creating the file.")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtDocument_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDocument.TextChanged
        ' Indicate the text has changed.
        blnIsChanged = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuFileNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileNew.Click

        ' Has the current document changed?
        If blnIsChanged = True Then
            ' Confirm before clearing the document.
            If MessageBox.Show("The current document is not saved." & "Are you sure?",
                                    "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) =
                                    Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                ClearDocument()
            End If
        Else
            ' Document has not changed, so clear it.
            ClearDocument()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuFileOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileOpen.Click

        ' Has the current document changed?
        If blnIsChanged = True Then
            ' Confirm before clearing and replacing
            If MessageBox.Show("The current document is not saved." & "Are you sure?",
                                    "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) =
                                    Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                ClearDocument()
                OpenDocument(Nothing)
            End If
        Else
            ' Document has not changed, so replace it.
            ClearDocument()
            OpenDocument(Nothing)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuFileSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileSave.Click

        ' Does the current document have a filename?
        If strFilename = String.Empty Then
            ' The Document has not been saved, so 
            'use Save As dialog box
            If sfdSaveFile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                strFilename = sfdSaveFile.FileName
                SaveDocument()
            End If
        Else
            ' Save the document with the current filename.
            SaveDocument()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuFileSaveAs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileSaveAs.Click
        ' Save the current document under a new filename.
        If sfdSaveFile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            strFilename = sfdSaveFile.FileName
            SaveDocument()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuFileExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileExit.Click
        ' Close form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuHelpAbout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuHelpAbout.Click
        ' Display an about box.
        MessageBox.Show("Simple Text Editor version 1.0")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

        ' If the document has been modified, confirm
        ' before editing.
        If blnIsChanged = True Then
            Dim result = MessageBox.Show("The current document is not saved. Do you wish to save " &
                               "your changes?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)

            If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                e.Cancel = False    ' Close, and
                SaveDocument()      ' Save current changes
            ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
                e.Cancel = False    ' Close without saving.
            Else
                e.Cancel = True     ' Cancel closing.
            End If
        End If
    End Sub


    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        ' Desktop path.
        Dim desktopPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop



        ' Open the default file upon opening program.
        strFilename = desktopPath & "/contacts_hw2.csv"
        OpenDocument(strFilename)

    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: are we to guess where in that code-dump  the error is? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The sub:

```
    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk

End Sub
```

handles the OpenFileDialog.FileOk event, but your OpenFileDialog appears to be called ofdOpenFile.

Change the definition of the Sub to be:

```
    Private Sub ofdOpenFile_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ofdOpenFile.FileOk

End Sub
```

or remove it.